# Automatically use LRT to assess significance of entire factor variable

Tags: r, regression, anova, categorical-data

R's output for a multivariable regression model including one or more factor variable does not automatically include a likelihood ratio test (LRT) of the significance of the entire factor variable in the model. For example:

```
fake = data.frame( x1=rnorm(100), x2=sample(LETTERS[1:4], 
       size=100, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(100) )

head(fake)
          x1 x2          y
1  0.6152511  A  0.7682467
2 -0.8215727  A -0.5389245
3 -1.3287208  A -0.1797851
4  0.5837217  D  0.9509888
5 -0.2828024  C -0.9829126
6  0.3971358  B -0.4895091

m = lm(fake$y ~ fake$x1 + fake$x2)
summary(m)
```

If we want to test the significance of the entire variable `x2` in the model, we can fit a reduced model `m.red` and use the LRT:

```
m.red = lm(fake$y ~ fake$x1)
anova(m, m.red, test="LRT")
```

But if you have many factor variables in a model, doing this over and over becomes ridiculous. I have to believe there is some built-in approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `drop1`:

```
drop1(m,test="Chisq")
## Single term deletions

## Model:
## fake$y ~ fake$x1 + fake$x2
##         Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC Pr(>Chi)
## <none>               79.814 -12.547         
## fake$x1  1   0.33741 80.152 -14.125   0.5160
## fake$x2  3   2.88510 82.699 -14.996   0.3142
```

Comment: This actually made my day.

Comment: Would you know if there's a way to get `drop1` to play nicely with `mice`, specifically `glm.mids`?

Comment: It looks like we'd need to use `pool.compare` somehow

Comment: that sounds not entirely trivial.  Why don't you ask another question (with another reproducible example)?

Comment: I was afraid of that. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621092/automatically-compare-nested-models-from-mices-glm-mids