# Automatically compare nested models from mice's glm.mids

Tags: r, anova, categorical-data, r-mice

I have a multiply-imputed model from R's `mice` package in which there are lots of factor variables. For example:

```
library(mice)
library(Hmisc)

# turn all the variables into factors
fake = nhanes
fake$age = as.factor(nhanes$age)
fake$bmi = cut2(nhanes$bmi, g=3) 
fake$chl = cut2(nhanes$chl, g=3) 

head(fake)
  age         bmi hyp       chl
1   1        <NA>  NA      <NA>
2   2 [20.4,25.5)   1 [187,206)
3   1        <NA>   1 [187,206)
4   3        <NA>  NA      <NA>
5   1 [20.4,25.5)   1 [113,187)
6   3        <NA>  NA [113,187)

imput = mice(nhanes)

# big model
fit1 = glm.mids((hyp==2) ~ age + bmi + chl, data=imput, family = binomial)
```

I want to test the significance of each *entire* factor variable in the model (not the indicator variables for each level) by testing the full model against each possible nested model that drops one variable at a time. Manually, I can do:

```
# small model (no chl)
fit2 = glm.mids((hyp==2) ~ age + bmi, data=imput, family = binomial)

# extract p-value from pool.compare
pool.compare(fit1, fit2)$pvalue
```

How can I do this automatically for all the factor variables in my model? The very helpful function `drop1` was suggested to me for [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618951/automatically-use-lrt-to-assess-significance-of-entire-factor-variable) -- now I want to do something exactly like that except for the `mice` case.

**Possibly helpful note:** An annoying feature of `pool.compare` is that it appears to want the "extra" variables in the larger model to be placed after the ones that are shared with the smaller model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop to iterate through the different combinations of predictors, after arranging them in the order required for `pool.compare`.

So using your `fake` data from above - tweaked the number of categories

```
library(mice)
library(Hmisc)
# turn all the variables into factors
# turn all the variables into factors
fake <- nhanes
fake$age <- as.factor(nhanes$age)
fake$bmi <- cut2(nhanes$bmi, g=2) 
fake$chl <- cut2(nhanes$chl, g=2) 

# Impute
imput <- mice(fake, seed=1)

# Create models 
# - reduced models with one variable removed
# - full models with extra variables at end of expression
vars <- c("age", "bmi", "chl")

red <- combn(vars, length(vars)-1 , simplify=FALSE)
diffs <- lapply(red, function(i) setdiff(vars, i) )
(full <- lapply(1:length(red), function(i) 
                            paste(c(red[[i]], diffs[[i]]), collapse=" + ")))
#[[1]]
#[1] "age + bmi + chl"

#[[2]]
#[1] "age + chl + bmi"

#[[3]]
#[1] "bmi + chl + age"

(red <- combn(vars, length(vars)-1 , FUN=paste, collapse=" + "))
#[1] "age + bmi" "age + chl" "bmi + chl"
```

The models are now in the correct order to pass to the `glm` call. I've also replaced `glm.mids` method as it has been replaced by `with.mids` - see `?glm.mids`

```
out <- vector("list", length(red))

for( i in 1:length(red)) {

  redMod <-  with(imput, 
               glm(formula(paste("(hyp==2) ~ ", red[[i]])), family = binomial))

  fullMod <-  with(imput, 
               glm(formula(paste("(hyp==2) ~ ", full[[i]])), family = binomial))

  out[[i]] <- list(predictors = diffs[[i]], 
                   pval = c(pool.compare(fullMod, redMod)$pvalue))
   }

do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
#    predictors      pval
#2         chl 0.9976629
#21        bmi 0.9985028
#3         age 0.9815831

# Check manually by leaving out chl
mod1 <- with(imput, glm((hyp==2) ~ age + bmi + chl , family = binomial))
mod2 <- with(imput, glm((hyp==2) ~ age + bmi , family = binomial))
pool.compare(mod1, mod2)$pvalue
#         [,1]
#[1,] 0.9976629
```

You will get a lot of warnings using this dataset

EDIT

You could wrap this in a function

```
impGlmDrop1 <- function(vars, outcome, Data=imput,  Family="binomial") 
{

  red <- combn(vars, length(vars)-1 , simplify=FALSE)
  diffs <- lapply(red, function(i) setdiff(vars, i))
  full <- lapply(1:length(red), function(i) 
                      paste(c(red[[i]], diffs[[i]]), collapse=" + "))
  red <- combn(vars, length(vars)-1 , FUN=paste, collapse=" + ")

  out <- vector("list", length(red))
  for( i in 1:length(red)) {

  redMod <-  with(Data, 
              glm(formula(paste(outcome, red[[i]], sep="~")), family = Family))
  fullMod <-  with(Data, 
              glm(formula(paste(outcome, full[[i]], sep="~")), family = Family))
  out[[i]] <- list(predictors = diffs[[i]], 
                   pval = c(pool.compare(fullMod, redMod)$pvalue)  )
  }
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
}

# Run
impGlmDrop1(c("age", "bmi", "chl"), "(hyp==2)")
```

Comment: This is awesome; thank you! I will be using this function for a paper that will be submitted shortly. I'd be very happy to acknowledge you if you'd be comfortable with that.

Comment: Great stuff, you're welcome - glad it works. Cheers, but no need to acknowledge  - all S.V. Buuren's hard work. (im sure you noticed this but the default test of `pool.compare` is the `Wald` approx, so if you are using logistic regression you should change this)